# Retrieve Arabic words alphabetically using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arabic

I want to view Arabic names in an alphabetical order.

My table:

[image]

Code:

```
<?php
    $dbhost="xx";
    $dbuser="xxx";
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser, "");
    if (!$con) 
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con,'xxx');; 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `boardteam` ORDER BY fName ASC";
    mysqli_query($con,"set character_set_server='utf8'");
    mysqli_query($con,"set fName 'utf8'");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ($result)
        {
            while($db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $tname ="";             
                switch ($db_field['titleName'])
                {
                    case "Dr":
                    $tname = "د.";
                    break;
                    case "Ms":
                    $tname = "السيدة.";
                    break;
                    case "Mr":
                    $tname = "السيد.";
                    break;
                }
            $members .= "<li><a href='browseMember.php?id=".$db_field['nationalID']."'>".$tname." ".$db_field['fName']." ".$db_field['sName']." ".$db_field['lName']."</a></li>";
            }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

FYI text appears in db like this:

[image]

Comment: try `mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");`

Comment: Works Great now it is stored correctly ^^ May God bless you Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```